# How to avoid pagenumering with text in scrlttr2

Tags: page-numbering, koma-script, scrlttr2

Have a Letter in `scrlttr2`. I cannot avoid/exclude the text before the page number 'Seite' (see print-screen). The [official documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) recommends to add `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. But for my document, it has no effect.

[image]

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass%%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [fontsize=12pt,%%          Schriftgroesse
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Satzspiegel
   paper=a4,%%               Papierformat
   enlargefirstpage=on,%%    Erste Seite anders
   pagenumber=footcenter,%%   Seitenzahl oben mittig
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Layout
   headsepline=on,%%         Linie unter der Seitenzahl
   parskip=half,%%           Abstand zwischen Absaetzen
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Formatierung
   draft=on%%                Entwurfsmodus
]{scrlttr2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Briefstil und Position des Briefkopfs
\LoadLetterOption{DIN} %% oder: DINmtext, SN, SNleft, KOMAold.
\makeatletter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Seitenstil
\pagestyle{plain}%% keine Header in der Kopfzeile
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{Herr\\
                Mustermann\\
               Straße 1\\
               12345 Stadt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomavar{subject}{Beispielschreiben}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\opening{Liebe Herr Mustermann,}

here is some Text.

\pagebreak

here is some Text.
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{letter}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there something *special* in your document, that it doesn't work? Can you show us a code example?

Comment: Good example, few hints: -- Instead of loading package `german`, load `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. -- Your `makeatletter` is a bit lonely there. -- DIN should is the default, no need to load it explicitely.

Comment: The title of this post is not particularly helpful for someone searching for an answer to this problem. I earlier posted [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577418/) before I became aware of this one. Perhaps it would offer some ideas for a change in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}
```

in your preamble. This removes `\pagename\`  (note the space) from the page numbering scheme.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Remove '\pagename\ ' from \pagemark
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Vielen Dank! :)

Comment: The author of KOMA-Script suggested to use `\newcommand*` instead of `\renewcommand` [here](https://komascript.de/node/1490), but clearly, it must be the latter, as shown in this answer. Apart from that, the author proposed exactly the same solution.

Comment: For the package `scrletter`, but not for `scrlttr2`, the solution works only if the `\renewcommand` instance appears inside a `letter` environment, rather than in the preamble.