# disable page prefix in KOMA-Script (scrletter)

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrletter

The  KOMA-Script package `scrletter` by default typesets the word "Page" (or language-dependent equivalent) preceding the actual page number in the footer.

How may this behavior be disabled, in favor of typesetting simply an unlabelled number?

---

See [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227521) for solution to this question for class `scrlttr2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine `\letterpagemark` in the preamble to get the desired result.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand*\letterpagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility would be

```latex
    \let\letterpagemark\pagemark
```

Then the same output of the page number will be used for the letter part and the other pages of the document. Note that a possible redefinition of `\pagemark` must be done before this line.

---

Explanation:

With KOMA-Script classes `\pagemark` serves to output the formatted page number.
While the main KOMA-Script classes (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook`) define `\pagemark` as

```latex
\newcommand*{%
  \pagemark
}{%
  {\usekomafont{pagenumber}{%
    \thepage}}}
```

the KOMA-Script letter class (`scrlttr2`) defines `\pagemark` as

```latex
\newcommand*{%
  \pagemark
}{%
  {\usekomafont{pagenumber}{%
    \pagename\nobreakspace
    \thepage}}}
```

So there will be the prefix `\pagename` in the output of the page number in KOMA-Script letters.

If package `scrletter` would redefine `\pagemark` to add the prefix, the output of the page number on non-letter pages would be changed, too. Therefore package `scrletter` defines `\letterpagemark`

```latex
\newcommand*{%
  \letterpagemark
}{%
  {\usekomafont{pagenumber}{%
    \pagename\nobreakspace
    \thepage}}}
```

and uses `\let\pagemark\letterpagemark` inside the letter part of the document.

Comment: Would it work as well simply to redefine `\pagename` to an empty value?

Comment: No. The `\nobreakspace` in the definition of `\pagemark` would shift the page number to the right.

Comment: Minor comment: I was wondering why your reference to "the KOMA-Script letter class" does not use its name, namely `scrlttr2`. Wouldn't that be clearer/more specific? Of course, one could mention that it is the KOMA-Script letter class too.