# How can I print “page # of ##” with the total page number in KOMA (scrartcl/scrletter)?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, lastpage, scrletter

[This questions explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227/98645) how you can show the total page number of your document in the footer on each page, i.e. show a “page # of ##” instead of the default “page # of #”.

However, [even though someone asked for that in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document#comment1043446_282840), it does not explain how to do that in a KOMA class. It has been suggested to ask a new question.

I use `scrartcl` for a letter (and load `scrletter`), so I'd like to do the same here.
So how can I do it there?

The previous question has been [asked about scrlttr2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577981/98645) [but the best solution there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578072/98645) **does not work in this case**. See example below.

Example code:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With package `scrletter` you have to redefine `\letterpagemark`:

```latex
\renewcommand*\letterpagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\renewcommand*\letterpagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Additional information can be found in the KOMA-Script documentation or at the end of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577516/43317).

---

If the document consits of only letters, you can also use

```latex
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
```

This would work with both `\documentclass{scrlttr2}` and `\documentclass{scrartcl}\usepackage{scrletter}`.